# Clearing a struct variable for re-assigning

Tags: c, variables, struct, unset

I have a function that returns a type of struct that I've defined:

```
typedef struct irPulseSet
{
    int pulseCount;
    int (*pulses)[2];
} irPulseSet;

irPulseSet irReadPulse()
{
    irPulseSet outputPulseSet;
    //some stuff
    return outputPulseSet;
}
```

But I'm calling it inside of a loop:

```
while(1)
{
   irPulseSet currentlPulseSet = irReadPulse();
   //some other stuff here
}
```

What I want to know is how I would unset `currentPulseSet`, so it can be set again in the next iteration of the while loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `currentlPulseSet` is living on the stack. When it goes out of scope it will be removed from memory automatically. You don't have to do anything.

Comment: So it goes out of stack at the end of each loop iteration?

Comment: Yes, try to use it in the while() or do-while() expression, what happens?